# Dealing with C# namespaces

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a project that will need to ability to download youtube videos. I found this project on github:

https://github.com/flagbug/YoutubeExtractor

My project already has a namespace. How would I import the YoutubeExtractor into my project? Do I need to change the namespace for it before (or after) importing it? Or is it up to me, in which case, what are the advantages and disadvantages to changing the namespace vs. not changing it? I am using VS Express 2012, if that matters.

Comment: do you understand the purpose of a namespace?

Comment: probably not. To me it was always just something I had to put at the top of each of my class files. I have never had to "use" a namespace before.

Comment: As a supplement: namespaces are a code organization mechanism. The goal is to reduce the probability of type name clashes across independently developed modules of code. You can (and it is often desirable) have many namespaces in one project, they can be anything you like. As a best practice, try to match your folder structure. eg MyNameOrCompanyName.ProjectName.UsefulClasses. Visual studio will automatically give namespaces to new classes that matches the projects folder structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My project already has a namespace. How would I import the YoutubeExtractor into my project?

You add reference to the external assembly (in this particular case you install the NuGet) and then add `using` statement with the correct namespace (`YoutubeExtractor`) in which the classes are defined.

So just follow the steps described on the home page:

```
Install-Package YoutubeExtractor
```

and then:

```
using YoutubeExtractor;
```

and finally:

```
// Our test youtube link
string link = "insert youtube link";

/*
* Get the available video formats.
* We'll work with them in the video and audio download examples.
*/
IEnumerable<VideoInfo> videoInfos = DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls(link);
```

Comment: +1, and you even had to show off didn't you :D? Had to show the command-line for `nuget`. You just make me proud every time I read an answer from you my friend!

Comment: I had not used nuget before. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the project that exists for the `YouTubeExtractor` and build it.
2. Move the outputted assembly to a location inside your project structure.
3. Add a reference to that assembly.
4. Add a `using {namespace}` to the files you want to use the extractor in.

Where `{namespace}` is the namespace it uses.

Further, it appears that there is a `nuget` package for it (you see that `YoutubeExtractor.nuspec` file in root). I would recommend installing `nuget` into Visual Studio and then searching `nuget` for the `YouTubeExtractor`. It's a lot easier, and you get updates with it easier as well.

Comment: Actually there's already a NuGet with it, no need to download and build the source: `Install-Package YoutubeExtractor`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, yeah I saw that after I wrote the initial answer. I always wonder though, does the author keep it updated?